# How to fix an error on Tizen 4.0? "Application Error" A client side exception has occurred

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tizen

We are in the process of testing an HTML link integration within a CMS application specifically designed for Digital Signage, operating natively on the Tizen OS.

Our application generates a URL that is fed through the CMS. Standard webpages and various other HTML links seem to function correctly.... however, we encounter a persistent issue with our HTML link - a blank white screen displaying an "Application Error: A client-side exception has occurred."

This particular issue seems to be exclusive to Tizen 4.0 and below, while versions 6.0 and above operate seamlessly with our link.

Despite our efforts in injecting ES6 Polyfill and optimizing specific areas to rectify this problem, the issue unfortunately is still there.

If anyone could offer guidance or advice on how to overcome this error, it would be super appreciated.